# VB.net get window information

Tags: vb.net

Can someone post the code that would allow me to read the postion and resolution of a specific window by its name, eg

```
private function findposition(byval windowtitle as string)
```

cheers
Martin

I am using

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias _
    "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal _
    lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr

Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal _
        hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpRect As Rectangle) As Integer

Dim lobbywindow As IntPtr = FindWindow("Appclass", "Appname")
Dim lobbyrectangle As New Rectangle

GetWindowRect(lobbywindow, lobbyrectangle)
```

Please assist in solving this since I get the error

A call to PInvoke function 'App!App.Form1::GetWindowRect' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Comment: Don't know why people downvote without commenting, I cant fix the problem if I dont know what it is.

Comment: Ah it was a code copy and paste error, no offence meant!

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need to use the Windows API and a similar problem is being described here: http://www.activevb.de/tipps/vb6tipps/tipp0111.html

You would need to implement

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias _
        "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal _
        lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal _
        hwnd As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long
```

Comment: It looks like the code came from a vb6 site, the Long's need to be integers for .Net

Comment: I am trying to use this but keep getting the error      'A call to PInvoke function 'App!App.Form1::GetWindowRect' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.'

Answer (score 2):

I assume it is for any window, even if external?  Something like this may help:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string className, string windowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out Rectangle rect);



    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string className = "yourClassName";
        string windowName = "yourWindowName";

        Rectangle rect;
        IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(className, windowName);
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rect);
    }
```

Comment: I know this is 10 years old, but this code produces incorrect results, because the RECT struct used by GetWindowRect is not the same as the `.NET System.Drawing.Rectangle`: it stores `Right` and `Bottom` instead of `Width` and `Height`. See https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowrect